# Scrolling up and down in tmux session on OSX iTerm 2 and Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook, tmux, iterm2

I have a Macbook Pro without dedicated PgUp and PgDown keys.

What would be proper way to configure iTerm 2 and tmux so that I can scroll back tmux buffer with Fn+Up and Fn+Down (I think these usually map to Page Up and Page Down on Macbook)?

I have tried various instructions and combos, but for some reason tmux resists my all attempts to scroll up and down. I manage to get scrollwheel scroll working, so that touchpad scrolls tmux buffer, but this works only *once* per session. The ability is lost after the first scroll and then touchpad scrolls the iTerm's own buffer (meaning statuslines do not stick at the bottom of the screen, you scroll up to see your `tmux a` command).

Is there something which I do not manage to understand about tmux or are iTerm + tmux just broken?

What other alternative keyboard shortcuts there are to scroll in tmux?

Answer (score 13):

I use the tmux from MacPorts, not the one from iTerm 2. With that tmux, hit the prefix key then page-up (fn-up arrow): <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd>